# Can't seem to remove underline style from image links?

Tags: html, css

The html is as follows:

```
<ul id="members">
    <li><a id="Chris"><img alt="Chris" src="images/chris.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li><a id="Carlin"><img alt="Carlin" src="images/bass2.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li><a id="Mikael"><img alt="Mikael" src="images/drums.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li><a id="Bert"><img alt="Bert" src="images/keyboard.jpg"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

What I am trying to achieve is these images positioned horizontally which I managed find but the images had an underline style. I know that to fix it I need `text-decoration:none` somewhere, the css I tried was:

```
#members { list-style: none; text-decoration: none; float:left; display: inline; }
#members li { list-style: none; text-decoration: none; border: none; float:left; display: inline; margin: 0px 75px 20px 0px; }
```

If I change the second line of the above css to:

```
 #members li a img { list-style: none; text-decoration: none; border: none; float:left; display: inline; margin: 0px 75px 20px 0px; }
```

Then the underline is removed but the images are then positioned vertically in a line instead of horizontally.

I know it's probably something really silly but I can't see what's causing it myself.

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
a,
a img {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    border: 0px none transparent;
}
```

The above removes the underline, the outline and borders from the `a` and the descendant `img`, it doesn't declare the `display` property, so the float should still work, though if you float the images, you may need to declare `overflow: hidden;` on the parent `a` or `li` elements.

Comment: @David Thomas, are there any practical situations were `border: none;` would not be enough? In what situations would `text-decoration: none;` and `outline: none;` do anything useful? And what is the difference between `border: 0px none transparent;`, `border: none;` and `border: 0px;`. I will up-vote you if you could briefly address these questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The underline is probably coming from the wrapping `<a>` tag, see if this works:

```
#members li a,
#members li a:visited
{ text-decoration: none; }

a img { outline: none; border: none; }
```

Comment: thanks, I now have this: `#members { list-style: none; text-decoration: none; float:left; display: inline; }
#members li { list-style: none; text-decoration: none; border: none; float:left; display: inline; margin: 0px 75px 20px 0px; }
#members li a, #members li a:visited { text-decoration: none; }` but those darn underlines are still there!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in this same situation was adding this to the beginning of my css file:

```
a:hover, a:visited, a:link, a:active
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It will remove the underlines.

This solution came from a blog on W3 School.